# Salesforce LWC - Breadcrumbs

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I am trying to create a breadcrumb using lwc component to display it on my community pages. I don't find a way to get the names of the pages dynamically. I need to use the same breadcrumb component in multiple pages, but it should be dynamic.

Here is what I have tried in my lwc template.

```
<template>
 <lightning-breadcrumbs>
    <lightning-breadcrumb
        label="My Home Page" href="" onclick={redirectHome}>
    </lightning-breadcrumb>
    <lightning-breadcrumb label="Sub page1" href="" onclick={redirectpage1}>
    </lightning-breadcrumb>
    <lightning-breadcrumb label="Sub page2" href="" onclick={redirectpage2}>
    </lightning-breadcrumb>
    </lightning-breadcrumbs></template>
```

In js, I am trying to set the home page something like this :

```
 redirectHome() {
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__namedPage',
        attributes: {
            pageName: 'home'
        },
    });
}
```

1. How to make the redirect function dynamic here?
2. How to display the current page name in the template?

Thanks in advance!